# how to use same reference variable to store multiple objects at different times without causing any affect to previously stored objects?

Tags: java

Let's say i have 4 previously instantiated objects called `o1`, `o2`, `o3`, `o4` of type `T`. 
I also have one reference variable called `vForAll` of type  `T`.
First I store o1 in vForAll as

```
VForAll = o1;
```

Then I want to store `o2` in `vForAll` without doing any affect on the `o1` object  and so on! 
What can I do?

Comment: What you just said won't affect previous values. so do what you said.

Comment: you could try use a Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, if `o1, o2, o3, o4` are just reference types, doing `vForAll = o2` should do the trick. The `o1` will not be modified.

Comment: Just make sure to hold other references to these objects, or they'll get garbage collected.

Comment: Does it change o2 as o1?

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean here. However, the best way to test the program, would be to just running your code and testing if it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you do vForAll = o2, vForAll will no longer point to o1, but o2.  Any changes you now make will only affect o2.

Want to change o1 after that, just do a vForAll = o1.